# Can't import MySql dump via kubectl

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, import, kubectl, dump

I'm struggling with import dump via `kubectl` to MySql database running in Kubernetes. There is no error output, but also no data imported.

Here is proof that there is such pod, also dump file on disk root called `/database.sql` and command.

```
root@node-1:~# kubectl get pods -n esopa-test | grep mariadb
esopa-test-mariadb-0                    1/1     Running     0          14d
root@node-1:~# ll /database.sql 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4418347 Oct 14 08:50 /database.sql
root@node-1:~# kubectl exec esopa-test-mariadb-0 -n esopa-test -- mysql -u root -proot database < /database.sql 
root@node-1:~#
```

Thank you for any advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy files from a pod to node by using [`kubectl cp`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#cp) command.

To copy files from pod to node syntax is very simple:

```
kubectl cp <some-namespace>/<some-pod>:<directory-inside-pod> <directory_on_your_node>
```

So in your use case you can use following command:

```
kubectl cp esopa-test/esopa-test-mariadb-0:/database.sql <directory_on_your_node>
```

And to copy files from node to pod you can use:

```
kubectl cp <directory_on_your_node> esopa-test/esopa-test-mariadb-0:/database.sql
```

Comment: I changed it according your advice and it works, thank you